# Import one FTL file inside another FTL file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have created one DIV inside a FTL file and that DIV contain form now say i have another FTL file and i want to use first FTL's div inside second FTL file is this possible

### deepak.ftl

```
<div id="filterReportParameters" style="display:none">
    <form method="POST" action="${rc.getContextPath()}/leave/generateEmpLeaveReport.json" target="_blank">
    <table border="0px" class="gtsjq-master-table">
        <tr>
            <td>From</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="empId" id="empId"/>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="height:20px;width:145px;"/>
            </td>
            <td>Order By</td>
            <td>
                <select name="orderBy" id="orderBy">
                    <option value="0">- - - - - - - Select- - - - - - - -</option>
                    <option value="1">Date</option>
                    <option value="2">Leave Type</option>
                    <option value="3">Transaction Type</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="height:20px;width:145px;"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave Type</td>
            <td>
                <select name="leaveType" id="leaveType">
                    <option value="0">- - - - - - - Select- - - - - - - -</option>
                    <#list leaveType as type>
                        <option value="${type.id}">${type.leaveType.description}</option>
                    </#list> 

                </select>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Leave Transaction</td>
            <td>
                <select name="transactionType" id="transactionType">
                    <option value="0">- - - - - - - Select- - - - - - - -</option>
                    <#list leaveTransactionType as leaveTransaction>
                        <option value="${leaveTransaction.id}">${leaveTransaction.description}</option>
                    </#list> 

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

How do i use this div in another FTL file

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to include the div from one freemarker template in another freemarker template you can extract the common div out by [using a macro](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_userdefdir.html).  For example,

```
in macros.ftl:
<#macro filterReportDiv>
    <div id="filterReportParameters" style="display:none">
      <form ...>
    ..
      </form>
    </div>
 </#macro>
```

Then in both your freemarker templates, you can import `macros.ftl` and invoke the macro via something like:

```
<#import "/path/to/macros.ftl" as m>
<@m.filterReportDiv />
```

Macros are a great feature in FreeMarker and can be parameterized as well - they can really cut down on code duplication in your templates.

Comment: In order to know how to load macro templates on that purpose, also read the manual about "template loading" chapter, located at https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html. It also explain the different ways of using `TemplateLoader`s. Too bad that the documentation does not mention the `StringTemplateLoader` class which is very helpful when the template source codes are available as `Strings`. Note also the reference about the macro import usage at https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_import.html.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`<#include>`](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_include.html) directive - the included file will be processed by Freemarker as though it was part of the including file.

`<#include "deepak.ftl">` will work if both the FTL files are in the same directory. You may use relative paths if they're not.

Comment: hi @no.good.at.coding. i have this multi module spring project in which i want to use a function.ftl file from one package in Entityt.ftl file that is in another package. import only works if i put function.ftl and Entity.ftl in same directory or it fails with the template not found exception. i need a little help from you in my question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070539/unable-to-import-a-ftl-file-inside-my-ftl-file-freemarker thanks!