# Include HTML information using template files

Tags: java, html, servlets, web, freemarker

In my web application I use Java Servlets and Freemarker Templates to generate the HTML output. After I have already set up several template files I would like to add a navigation bar throughout all templates. I would like to avoid adding the necessary HTML code to each template file, since when I change it I have to do it all over again.

What is best practice in this case? The only solution I have thought of is defining the navigation bar in another text file and add it through template processing, something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
${navigationBarConent}
...
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import one FTL file inside another FTL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040047/import-one-ftl-file-inside-another-ftl-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahoni,

If I understand you correctly, this may help.

http://richardbarabe.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/freemarker-a-brief-example/

Comment: The #include statement, perfect!

Answer (score -1):

As you are using freemarker. I think better to add in each template file so that it justifies the use of templates.

Use Apache Tiles.It will create jsp page template with additional features.
http://tiles.apache.org/.

Comment: I am using Java Servlets with Freemarker, I didn't want a suggestion for another framework.