# Importing freemarker macros

Tags: java, import, macros, freemarker

My `macros.txt` file is

```
<#macro macro1>
Helloworld.
</#macro>
```

I have another file `testMacro.txt`. I want to use this macro inside the file `testMacro.txt`. 
I have tried the following

```
<#import "./macros.txt" as my>
<@my.macro1 />
```

But it does not seem to be working.

In my java file, where I am working with the template file, I have(in my MacroWorking.java)

```
template = new Template(null,new FileReader("testMacro.txt"),new configuration());
```

Exception are.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at freemarker.core.LibraryLoad.<init>(LibraryLoad.java:82)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.Import(FMParser.java:1727)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2389)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.Content(FMParser.java:2618)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:2786)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:2958)
at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:149)
at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:172)
at msjava.hdom.examples.DbQuery.main(MacroWorking.java:24)
```

Line 24 of MacroWorking.java is the one given above.

EDIT: With the same code but with my `testMacro.txt` having text as `HELLOWORLD` only, i.e. no import statement, then it works fine.
What do I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to check the objects in line 24 for `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with those templates, the problem is with the way you are using the Java API of FreeMarker.

When `#import` tries to resolve the `./macros.txt` path, it tries to resolve it relatively to the path of the current template, but since the template was loaded from a `Reader` and you have passed `null` as template name (that's the same as the template path), it will run into an NPE situation. That's an improper error message, but it couldn't resolve that path anyway, as it has no idea where the current template came from (remember, you have only given a `Reader` to FreeMarker). The proper way is:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/where/you/store/the/templates"));

Template template = cfg.getTemplate("testMacro.txt");
```

Now FreeMarker sets the name of the template to `testMacro.txt` and it also takes care of loading and caching of it. If you still need to load templates directly from a `Reader`, you can do it as:

```
Template template = new Template("testMacro.txt", new FileReader(...), cfg);
```

Note the non-null template name. It doesn't mater if that's real, but it will be used to resolve relative paths in that template. Also note that the template-loader must be set correctly in the `Configuration`, because FreeMarker works with virtual-paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, will still need to dig deeper into this a bit.

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040047/import-one-ftl-file-inside-another-ftl-file, the documentation about "template loading" chapter is located at freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html. It explains the different ways of using `TemplateLoader`s. Too bad that it does not mention the `StringTemplateLoader` class which is very helpful when the template source codes are available as `String`s, which may be what you were looking for.