# How can I correctly import an header and a footer page into a FreeMarker page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am working on a Spring MVC application that use **FreeMarker** for my views.

I am absolutly new in **FreeMarker** and I have the following problem: in my projct I have 3 files that have to be assemblet togheter into a single page.

So I have:

1) **header.ftl** representing the header of all my pages, somthing like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js is-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Registrazione -  MY WEBSITE</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/webfont.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bs-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/plugins/bs-dialog/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />

    </head>

    <body id="main">

        <!-- versione per popup. non prendere in considerazione -->
        <!--
        <div class="container page-header">
            <h1>MY WEBSITE</h1>
        </div>
```

2) **footer.ftl** representing the footer of all my pages:

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/bs-select/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bs-select/i18n/defaults-it_IT.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/bs-dialog/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/jq-form-validation/jquery.validation.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/functions.lib.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/form-validation.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

3) Then I have my specific page (named **myPage.ftl** that represent only the content, something like this:

```
<h1>This is the content</h1>
<p>Some inforamation</p>
```

The **header.ftl** and the **footer.ftl** are into this directory **\WEB-INF\freemarker\layout** of my project.

So my problem is: how can I import the **header.ftl** content above the content of the **myPage.ftl** and the **footer.ftl** under the content of **myPage.ftl** page?

Comment: This is literally the second result when searching for "freemarker import" in Google: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import one FTL file inside another FTL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040047/import-one-ftl-file-inside-another-ftl-file)

Comment: duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040047/import-one-ftl-file-inside-another-ftl-file

Comment: The question is not about importing so much as page templating, so simply linking to docs on the include directive doesn't really answer the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this using user-defined macros for page layouts, e.g. let's call your layout `standardPage.ftl`:

```
<#macro standardPage title="">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>${title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <#include "/include/header.ftl">    

    <#nested/>

    <#include "/include/footer.ftl">    
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

Then you can call this macro in each of your pages, e.g. `homePage.ftl`:

```
<#include "/pages/standardPage.ftl" />

<@standardPage title="Home">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <p>This bit replaces the nested tag in the layout</p>
</@standardPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation recommand to not using include anymore so i do it like so with macro :

```
<#import "partials.ftl" as partials>
<#macro emailLayout>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <body>
    <@partials.header/>
    <#nested>
    <@partials.footer/>
  </body>
</html>
</#macro>
```